# Meta-based navigation + shift-selection

Tags: keyboard

Say I have `beginning-of-line` bound to `M-a`. At least for me, holding shift gives: M-S-a translates to M-A translates to M-a and emacs doesn't do any shift selection.

It's the same when binding keys -- I gotta bind `M-A`, binding `M-S-a` doesn't work. Why is this? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Are you using the terminal version of emacs?

Comment: No that's what's weird. GUI on arch, emacs 25.3.1

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
(bind-key "M-a" (lambda ()
                  "Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line. If point was already at that position, move point to beginning of line."
                  (interactive "^")
                  (let ((oldpos (point))) (back-to-indentation) (and (= oldpos (point)) (beginning-of-line)))))
```

Note: "^" is required to support shift selection.

Comment: what does "^" do in interactive?

Comment: It's used for shift selection.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html

Answer (score 0):

If option **`shift-select-mode`** is `nil` then shift-selection does not work (it is turned off).

If it is not working for you even with a non-`nil` value, starting from `emacs -Q`, then consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: so you can bind M-S-a? tried it?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: I don't understand your question. Yes, at least on a graphic display (GUI) you can bind `M-S-a` (aka `M-A`).

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to be a problem with shift base navigation at all, it is just that certain navigation commands does not respect shift selection. I guess I will open a new question then

Comment: It works for me, with that navigation command. It should work for you, I think.  Again, if it doesn't, consider filing a bug report.

Comment: So let me ask, does (global-set-key ("M-S-a") ...) work for you? If it does, maybe it's some aliasing thing specific to my keyboard/xmodmap.

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: I already answered that question, in my first comment: Yes, it works for me, on a graphic display.